# How do I change the WinGHCi editor via :set editor?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want to use Notepad++ instead of Notepad as the editor GHCi calls when I type in `:edit`. Does anyone know how to do this? I tried

```
:set editor C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
:set editor "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"
```

but none of these work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The editor is a `String`, so you need to escape `\` as `\\`, like so:

```
:set editor "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++"
```

but it's unix/windows agnostic for FilePaths, so you could alternatively do it as

```
:set editor "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++"
```

As a side note, it's quicker to type `:e` instead of `:edit`; ghci will deduce what you mean from a substring like `:ed` if there's only one possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this one.  The top answer is correct however I could only get this working by adding -multiInst to the command line i.e:

```
:set editor "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst
```

or just

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst
```

in the settings dialog of WinGHCi which opens a new notepad++ instance on :e.

Comment: In GHCi and WinGHCi, I'm getting a `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I've tried double forward/backward slashes to no avail :(

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that Notepad++ should be on your $PATH. If you can run Notepad++ from a newly-opened terminal, then you're good. Then use `:set editor Notepad++` in ghci.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new system environment variable called EDITOR to your system environment variables if you want to use the editor you like permenantly.

Attentions:

1. You should add it to your system environment variables, not user's environment variables.
2. EDITOR should be all capitalized.
3. Most importantly, the value of this variable should be:

   - a Using double backslashes.
   - b keep the quotation marks! (like this: "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code", I think other variables might not have or need this quotation marks, but it NEEDs in this case.)

Comment: @Luciano Windows DOS system cut off string paths when it go through these paths and meet a whitespace, you can use quatation marks for a try! ^ _ ^